# JNDI Shiro PostgreSQL - Unable to look up javax.sql.DataSource with jndi name 'jdbc/postgres' in Apache Isis

Tags: postgresql, jndi, shiro, isis

I have downloaded the Apache Isis' simple-app archetype 1.15.0. And I would like to integrate it with Apache Shiro following this [documentation](https://isis.apache.org/guides/ugsec/ugsec.html#_ugsec_shiro-realm-implementations_jdbc-realm) . But i got some error like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to look up javax.sql.DataSource with jndi name 'jdbc/postgres'.
```

Have a look at my  in my **web.xml**

```
<resource-ref>
<description>db</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/postgres</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

and my **shiro.ini**:

```
jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm        

jof = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory          
jof.resourceName = jdbc/postgres
jof.requiredType = javax.sql.DataSource
jof.resourceRef = true

jdbcRealm.dataSource = $jof

jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery =         \
        select password                 \
          from users                    \
         where username = ?

jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery =              \
        select r.label                  \
          from users_roles ur           \
    inner join roles r                  \
            on ur.role_id = r.id        \
         where user_id = (              \
            select id                   \
             from users                 \
            where username = ?);        \

jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery=             \
        select p.permission             \
          from roles_permissions rp     \
    inner join permissions p            \
            on rp.permission_id = p.id  \
         where rp.role_id = (           \
            select id                   \
             from roles                 \
            where label = ?);

jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled=true

dps = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
pm = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
pm.passwordService = $dps
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $pm

securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your container. The Apache-Isis doc does have a link to how to configure this on Tomcat though:

> Using the above configuration you will also need to setup a DataSource. The details vary by servlet container, for example this is [how to do the setup on Tomcat 8.0](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).